# Unrecognized ethernet controller

Tags: networking, ethernet, adapter, device-manager

My network adapter stopped working recently. I had to do a fresh install of my win 7 OS anyway but after the install, the network adapter is not recognized anymore.

No problem I said, I'll jsut find some apropiate drivers on the internet or something.

The problem I currently encounter though, is that I cannot find the model of my network adapter. Device manager just lists it as unknown. No brand, no model.

So, how can I find out the brand/model of my network adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In Device Manager, right-click the unrecognized device and select Properties.
2. Go to the Details tab and select "Hardware IDs" from the drop-down.
3. Pray to Google for revelations on their meaning.

Comment: Pretty kool. That worked and pretty much answered my question. Now only if I could find a realiable source to download RTL8129 driver :P Any ideas ?

Comment: If it came in your computer, check your manufacturer's website.

Comment: I like 3. - it tickles my unix-ness

Comment: This computer was made by me years ago when I still had almost no clue about PC's. It was made from all sorts of random parts.

Comment: So, I'm guessing you've already tried physically inspecting the card?

Comment: Not that much of a hardware guru unfortunately. I just opened the case, saw the little metal cube that seemed to be my ethernet card and that's about it. Though now that I know the model all i have to do is find the proper drivers to find out wheter the drivers are messed or fi ti's alctually broken or smth. RTL8129 seems to be an enigma. Can't find it on the official Realtek site. I'm supposing it's deprecated or something and my previous WIN 7 installation was recognizing it by some misused other driver versions which will probabily take ages for me to find =(